# What scorpion is this and is it lethal?

Tags: species-identification

[image]

Found indoors in Florianopolis, Brazil.

Is able to hang from a web like something inside the jar.

[image]

Comment: I have another photo of the underside but cannot add because of reputation.

Comment: It's it a spider? Had it been a scorpion it would have been armed with a  sting.

Comment: It is a spider. Note the spinnerets at the caudal end of the abdomen, and the absence of claws. An eye pattern would be really nice; I think it's a jumping spider of some kind.